# How to change windows embedded handheld language (Pidion PDA)?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-embedded, pushdown-automaton

I'm using a Pidion BP 6000 PDA with Windows embedded handle (based on windows mobile 6.5)
Most of the system language are in Korean, some in English.
How to change the system language to English?

p/s: the weir thing is, checking the system infomation -> software -> language, it says "English", but the whole system is Korean major.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact a Bluebird Pidion partner.

The device is available with english, korean or chinese OS, AFAIK from internet.

Possibly Bluebird offers another OS image you can flash onto the BIP 6000.

Possibly the device will ask for the language on the first cold boot. Ask Bluebird support how to reflash the device to get this prompt.

Even in a korean OS image not all GUI is showing in korean.